# My Menu button is moving vertically up as I shrink my Browser

Tags: html, css

I have made a typical menu button. But for some reason when I shrink browser it starts to move slightly up? It's probably something simple but I don't know why? It's also very irritating!

```
<div id="lines" onClick="return showMenu()" class="btn"></div>


#lines:hover {
  background-color:#a2a2a2;
}

.btn { 
  position: relative;         
  margin-top:2%; 
  border: 2px solid #a5aaaa;
  border-radius: 2px; 
  height: 36px; 
  width:36px;  
  float:right;
  right:20px;
  position:relative;
}

#lines:before { 
  border-bottom: 17px double #a5aaaa;
  border-top: 6px solid #a5aaaa;    
  content:"";
  height: 5px; 
  position: absolute; 
  right:3px;  
  top: 4px; 
  width:30px;   
}
```

Comment: It's the `margin-top:2%;` in your rules for `.btn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

margin-top:0 for .btn

http://jsfiddle.net/g36Va/

```
#lines:hover {
  background-color:#a2a2a2;
}

.btn { 
  position: relative;         
  margin-top:0; 
  border: 2px solid #a5aaaa;
  border-radius: 2px; 
  height: 36px; 
  width:36px;  
  float:right;
  right:20px;
  position:relative;
}

#lines:before { 
  border-bottom: 17px double #a5aaaa;
  border-top: 6px solid #a5aaaa;    
  content:"";
  height: 5px; 
  position: absolute; 
  right:3px;  
  top: 4px; 
  width:30px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just setting the Margin top to 2%, which is a percentage of the page height.

Try setting it as following:

```
margin-top:2px;
```

or whatever value you like.

You just need a static value not a dynamic one that keep calculating the value each time window get re-sized.